# Typescript: one of two types works not correct for interface key

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an interface:

```js
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  createdAt: Timestamp | Date;
}
```

And in one of my components template I read property:

```html
<span>{{ user.createdAt._seconds }}</span>
```

But in my terminal, I got the next errors

> Property '_seconds' does not exist on type 'Date | Timestamp'.
>     Property '_seconds' does not exist on type 'Date'.

It exists in type `Timestamp`, but it looks like typescript does not care about it and throwing errors because this property does not exist in type `Date`.

Comment: Can you console.log() the populated user object inside component ts file? What does it look like?

Comment: It exists in type `Timestamp`, but it does not exist in type `Date` and TS can't tell wether in this particular case `createdAt` contains a `Timestamp` or a `Date`. So it's a 50/50 chance that the property won't be there when the code is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible I'd recommend transforming into a single type before passing to the template. If not here are two options:

#### Cast Value

If you know its always going to be a timestamp in that situation:

```html
<span>{{ (user.createdAt as Timestamp)._seconds }}</span>
```

#### Check Instance Type

```html
<span>{{ user.createdAt instanceof Timestamp ? user.createdAt._seconds : user.createdAt.getSeconds() }}</span>
```